# Keeping track of moving sprites in 2D grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, grid

I'm working on a 2D tower defence game in C++.

The game world consists of a grid of `Cell`s, that are managed by a `Map`:

Essentially the map is:

```
[cell][cell][cell][cell][cell]
[cell][cell][cell][cell][cell]
[cell][cell][cell][cell][cell]
[cell][cell][cell][cell][cell]
```

And mobs are moving across the map.

`Map` class:

```
class Map{
     //...
     std::vector<std::vector<Cell>> cells;
     std::unordered_set<Cell*> cellsContainingMobs;
     void addCellContainingMob(Cell* c);
     Cell* getCellFromPos(const glm::vec2& pos);

}
```

`Cell` class:

```
class Cell{
     //...         
     std::deque<Mob*> mobsInCell;
     void addMob(Mob* m);
     void clearMobs();
}
```

`Mob`s are a moving sprites that "walk" around the map and are managed by another class.

My goal is to at every game loop/frame, I know *which cells contains mobs* (`Map::cellsContainingMobs`), and for each of those cells, I know *which mobs are in the cell* (`Cell::mobsInCell`).

My current method for keeping track of this, is on each game loop iteration (frame) I do the following:

**Clear my containers:**

```
for (Cell* c : cellsContainingMobs){
    c->clearMobs(); //calls clear on the std::deque
 }
 cellsContainingMobs.clear();
```

**Iterate over active mobs in the scene**

- Find out which cell the mob is in (this is inexpensive, as the truncated coordinates of the `Mob`'s position is the indices of the `Cell` in `Map::cells`.
- Add the `Cell` to the `Map::cellsContainingMobs`. Since this is an `std::unordered_set` if the same `Cell` is added multiple times, it will only keep one.
- Add the `Mob` to the `Cell` it is currently at.

part of code:

```
for (Mob* m : activeMobs) {
    Cell* c = map->getCellFromPos(m->getPos());
    map->addCellContainingMobs(c);
    c->addMob(m);
}
```

I use `std::unordered_set` for `Map::cellsContainingMobs` to prevent keeping the same items multiple times. For `Cell::mobsInCell` I could probably use `std::vector` instead of `std::deque`, but I think the reason was that I don't need random access.

The reason I want to keep track of which Cells contains Mobs, and which Mobs are in which Cells, is to later make it more efficient to check for collision with Tower that shoots bullets. (I only check for collisions on the Cells that have mobs and are in the range of the tower).

My question is; should I use different type of containers for what I'm doing? Is there a completely different approach for keeping track of where my Mobs are located, that could be more efficient?

Comment: What does your profiler say? Generally speaking, if the code works and is clear to you and your teammates (which I think is the case here), if there is no bottleneck shown by profiling your game in its actual context, it's safe to assume that the code is ok and that time should now be spent on the next issue/feature.

Comment: The code works, and makes sense for the "team" (working alone on this).
I tested with VS Analyzer, at it looks like `Cell::clearMobs` (`std::deque::clear()`) and `Map::addCellContainingMobs` (`std::undordered_set::insert()`) uses the most processing time in my Game loop. 

That is, when I have few Towers compared to Mobs. (With many towers and few mobs, the towers will do the most work, which makes perfectly sense though.)

It is not a problem yet, but I will do some stress tests to see if it can be a problem.